# DRY way to stack multiple metrics with d3.layout.stack()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a d3.js [Streamgraph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/stream.html) to show sales over time.  Then I've got a transition to show profit over the same period.  The data looks like this:

```
var data = [{
    "name": "apples",
    "sales": [{
        "x": 0,
        "y": 941
    }, {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 490
    }],
    "profit": [{
        "x": 0,
        "y": 6
    }, {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 3
    }]
}, {
    "name": "oranges",
    "sales": [{
        "x": 0,
        "y": 344
    }, {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 425
    }],
    "profit": [{
        "x": 0,
        "y": 3
    }, {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2
    }]
}];
```

It works, but I'm currently generating the stacked data in a somewhat ham-fisted way, applying [stack.values](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#wiki-values) twice:

```
var stack_sales = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("wiggle")
    .values(function(d) { return d.sales; });

var stack_profit = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("wiggle")
    .values(function(d) { return d.profit; });

stack_sales(data);
stack_profit(data);
```

I've been getting into [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) but can't see the DRY way to do this.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to define the values function dynamically:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack().offset("wiggle");
["sales", "profit"].forEach(function(metric) {
  stack.values(function(d) { return d[metric]; })(data);
});
```

Another option would be to transpose your data so that the metrics are on the outside and the series are on the inside:

```
var metrics = [
  {
    "name": "sales",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "apples",
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": 941}, 
          {"x": 1, "y": 490}
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "name": "oranges",
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": 344}, 
          {"x": 1, "y": 425}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "profits",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "apples",
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": 0}, 
          {"x": 1, "y": 6}
        ]
      }, 
      {
        "name": "oranges",
        "values": [
          {"x": 0, "y": 1}, 
          {"x": 1, "y": 3}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Then you can access the values statically:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("wiggle")
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; });

metrics.forEach(function(metric) {
  stack(metric.series);
});
```

Comment: @mbostock, could you lend some insight on why we need to transpose the data in the first place (that is, why `d3.layout.stack()` works like it does)? It seems like the things being stacked are the data points that belong to the original categories. Why the need for the intermediate step? Speed?